# Когда меняю местами столбцы в datagridview данные не сохраняются!

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Windows Forms. Есть Datagridview. В него можно загружать таблицу Excel. После загрузки можно удалить столбец, удалить строку и поменять место колонки. После изменения места колонки - она не меняется в данных, а только визуально. Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Написать C# код, который будет менять колонки местами?

Comment: По подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Как тогда узнать, что я перетащил из одного индекса в другой, если данные не меняются? В инете нет подобного, что странно. Бред какой-то, я первый кто с этим столкнулся? Мне кажется, что это такая элементарная вещь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось куда мудренее.
На момент считывания данных с таблицы, необходимо инициализировать каждый столбец вот таким способом:

```c#
DataGridViewColumnCollection columnCollection = dataGridView1.Columns;
DataGridViewColumn one = columnCollection.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
DataGridViewColumn two = columnCollection.GetNextColumn(one, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None);
DataGridViewColumn three = columnCollection.GetNextColumn(two, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None);
DataGridViewColumn four = columnCollection.GetNextColumn(three, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None);

// Только сейчас можно с уверенностью получить данные из нужной ячейки вот так:

data = dataGridView1[one.Index, i].Value.ToString(),
```